# Ford Parking Brake on Right Side Calliper Acting Up

Tags: ford, parking-brake

[image]

After manually moving this lever down with my hand, the subsequent parking brake application works fine. However, after releasing the parking brake, only on the right side calliper, this arm doesn't fully come down back to where it was (on the left side calliper, it does). And subsequent applications of the parking brake after that are not as strong.

Looking at the setup here, it's the spring who's job it is to return that lever arm down and it just doesn't have enough strength to do so.

I'm thinking about loosening the nut here to fix the issue but I really do see 2 major flaws in my whole analysis/guess of what's happening here so I haven't touched anything yet.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you thought about just putting some lubricant on the moving parts (keeping it away from the braking parts, of course)? And don't loosen the nut. It's ONLY job is to keep the lever in place. You will do nothing by loosening it, other than the potential of losing the net and the plate. Also, it's more than likely the cable on that side which is having issues ... at least I'm assuming it's a cable which is tugging on that thing?

Comment: You're very right about trying lubricant. Will attempt that. I don't think it's the cable since it's completely out of tension and the lever arm is still not returning down.

Comment: There will likely be a failing rubber seal on the calliper side of that lever.  Corrosion has probably started on the shaft inside the calliper and is making the shaft difficult to turn.  You may be able to lubricate if and move it back and forward to give it some life.

Comment: Applied silicone lube yesterday. Works perfect now. Thanks guys. Hopefully it lasts a decent amount of time.

Comment: Update for anyone reading this in the future: lube fixed it for about 3 weeks and then it went back to being broken. I ended up replacing calipers on both sides and now it's gone for good.